# Issue with posting a score to Fb from iOS (flash, air) app

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash

The game is written on flash/as3, I'm using the Facebook ANE from freshplanet.

The call is done like that:

```
var data:Object = new Object();
data.score = 300;
data.access_token  = _facebook.accessToken;
_facebook.requestWithGraphPath("/me/scores", data, "POST", onScoreSubmitted);
```

The result is:

```
{"error":{"code":100,"message":"(#100) The parameter score is required","type":"OAuthException"},"accessToken":"CAAGN..."}
```

Other requests like `_facebook.requestWithGraphPath("/me"...), _facebook.requestWithGraphPath("/me/picture.type(large)"...)` works well (return the desired data.

So I'm a bit blocked with the score posting (especially with the error type). Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you sure, that you can update scores with `me/scores`? Try construction `userId/scores`

Comment: it doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong - both the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/scores/#publish) and the graph explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) say the same thing. Try `_facebook.requestWithGraphPath("/me/scores", {score:123}, "POST", onScoreSubmitted);`

Comment: @NicolasSiver /me will always result to the individual UserID of the attachted Access Token, so this is fine.

Comment: Tried passing the score directly `{score:123}` and construction `userId/scores` - the same issue `"code":100,"message":"(#100) The parameter score is required"`.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the permissions or app config/settings on Fb, but I guess the error msg would be different.

Comment: Use GET instead of POST

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, here it is:  `_facebook.requestWithGraphPath("/me/scores?score=123"...`

Comment: You don't use an access_token, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

> You can read the score for people playing your game by issuing an HTTP
>   GET request to /USER_ID/scores with a user access_token.

```
var data:Object = new Object();
data.score = 300;
data.access_token  = _facebook.accessToken;
_facebook.requestWithGraphPath("/me/scores", data, "GET", onScoreSubmitted);
```

Just replace POST with GET